# tinyproxy - abyssmal performance

Tags: performance, proxy, linux-networking, openwrt, tinyproxy

I installed tinyproxy on a GL-AR750s router (running dd-wrt).  Performance is abyssmal.

When I load MSN non-proxied, non-cached on my laptop, it takes about 3 seconds.  When I load MSN on the same laptop, run through tinyproxy, it takes more than 30 seconds.  A simple page, like http://example.com loads quickly via proxy.

It shouldn't be an issue of inadequate hardware, because squid on the same router performs well.

When I'm waiting on tinyproxy, 'top' indicates it is consuming only a few percent of CPU.  That suggests it is waiting on something.

What can I look at to see what it is waiting for?

Comment: You can `strace` the tinyproxy process. https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/issues/198 indicates it might be trying to resolve the ip of the client.

Comment: @Mark_Wagner: Good suggestions. I put entries in /etc/hosts for my client, so that's out.  I ran strace and found it repeatedly locking and unlocking /tmp/tinyproxy.servers.lock.jHcfek, and then sleeping 5 sec. Again and again. It is waiting on something to happen to that lock file.  Time for me to Use The Source.